# Force kaminari to start new page based on count or object parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I have a set of objects that I would like to paginate in a bit of a unconventional way. Some objects have a file attached and some don't. The behavior I would like is for the first set of objects without a file attached to be shown on the first set of pages and then for the objects with a file attached to be displayed on the following pages.

So if objects 1-10 have no attachments, and there are 8 objects viewed per page. I would like page one to have 8, and then page 2 to have only 2 objects, and the arrow to proceed to the next page. The remainder of the pages should paginate normally with the remaining objects with files attached, each with 8 per page.

I've looked at some code here:
[How to set different page size for the first page in Kaminari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489398/how-to-set-different-page-size-for-the-first-page-in-kaminari)
This allows custom counts on the first page using padding, but haven't got it working correctly and wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: If you have a total of 20 objects, with 8 objects viewed per page, and 10 are with attachment, then help me divide them into the 3 pages so that I can understand your concern better. Also for the situation where only 6 are with attachment?

Comment: Hi Guatam, thanks for your reply. I think I've figured this out. What I did was add a scope to the model for getting a count of those that have attachments. Then I did some math to determine the numbers left over for the last page of records w/o attachments. I then leveraged the use of offsets and limits as shown in the question I linked to get the desired effect.